# Handling checks with multiple checkboxes React

Tags: html, reactjs, checkbox, jsx

I have created a component that uses several checkboxes rendered in a `.map` function.
When I was testing the functionality I noticed that you could check multiple checkboxes at once. Seeing as the component is used as a filtering menu for another component having multiple checks at once wouldn't make sense to the users.

Here's a visual example:

[image]

This doesn't affect functionality in any way are is more of a visual bug.
Even so, I would still like to know a method for ensuring only one checkbox can be checked at once rather than multiple.

Here's the component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const checkboxes = [
    {
        heading : 'Price',

        labels : [
            {
                label: 'Up to £39.99',
                filter: '0',
                filterLimit: '39.99',
            },
            {
                label: '£40 to £59.99',
                filter: '40',
                filterLimit: '59.99',
            },
            {   
                label: '£60 to £79.99',
                filter: '60',
                filterLimit: '79.99',
            },
            {
                label: '£80 to £99.99',
                filter: '80',
                filterLimit: '99.99',
            },
            {
                label: '£100 to £199.99',
                filter: '100',
                filterLimit: '199.99',
            },
        ],
    },

    {
        heading : 'Brand',

        labels : [
            {
                label: 'BrandA',
                filter : 'BrandA',
            },
            {
                label: 'BrandB',
                filter: 'BrandB',
            },
            {
                label: 'BrandC',
                filter: 'BrandC',
            },
            {
                label: 'BrandD',
                filter: 'BrandD',
            },
            {
                label: 'BrandE',
                filter: 'BrandE',
            },
        ],
    },
];

export default function Sidebar(props) {
    const isntDesktop = props.isntDesktop;

    const sidebar = props.sidebar;
    const setSidebar = props.setSidebar;

    const setLoading = props.setLoading;
    const setFilter = props.setFilter;
    const setFilterLimit = props.setFilterLimit;

    return (
        <>
            {/* Overlay */}
            {sidebar && isntDesktop && (
                <div className="h-screen w-screen absolute top-0 right-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-60 backdrop-blur"></div>
            )}

            {/* Sidebar */}
            {sidebar && (
                <div class="lg:w-1/4 h-screen absolute right-0 top-0 z-10 lg:relative p-20 lg:px-5 lg:py-2 space-y-5 rounded bg-gray-100 lg:bg-gray-50">
                    {/* Close button */}
                    {isntDesktop && (
                        /* Attribution: https://heroicons.com */
                        <svg 
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
                            fill="none" 
                            viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
                            stroke-width="1.5" 
                            stroke="currentColor" 
                            onClick={() => setSidebar(!sidebar)}
                            class="w-6 h-6 absolute right-5 top-5 cursor-pointer" 
                        >
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                        </svg>
                    )}

                    {/* Checkboxes */}
                    {checkboxes.map((checkbox, index) => {
                        return (
                            <>
                                <div key={index}>
                                    <h3 class="text-base text-gray-600 font-bold">{checkbox.heading}</h3>

                                    {checkbox.labels.map((label, index) => {
                                        return (
                                            <div
                                                key={index}
                                                onClick={() => {
                                                    setLoading(true);
                                                    setFilter(label.filter);
                                                    setFilterLimit(label.filterLimit);
                                                }}
                                                class="mt-2.5"
                                            >
                                                <input class="h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm bg-white accent-sky-600 focus:outline-none transition duration-200 mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2 cursor-pointer" type="checkbox" />
                                                <label class="inline-block text-gray-500">
                                                    {label.label}
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        )
                                    })}
                                </div>

                                <hr class="border-gray-300" />
                            </>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: So.. prices can be selected only once, but brands can be multiple selected ?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying the brand section is a work in progress and wont remain how it currrently is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `checked` attribute on your Radio Input Elements`
like so:

```
<input type="radio" value="value" checked={selectedOption === 'value'} />
```

If you want a default one checked set `checked={true}`

Hope this help get you on the right path :) please accept if it is helpful

Comment: What do you suggest putting as `selectedOption` with the context of my component? Maybe checked state or something similar?

Comment: I can't tell you that exactly because you have to decide what value it is that you want. From what I can say is that your value would be your `label`. Hint you can keep the selected value in state.